# Why parameter server so heavy in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

We profile parameter server of Tensorflow, and found parameter server apply gradient op only consume 20us, but RunGraphAsync in parameter server totally takes about 200us(gradients are sent with RunGraphAsync RPC call, without fragmented GRPC request inside recv op).

What's the reason that have a so heavy parameter server design in Tensorflow?

My understanding is that ops could be reused both for single or cluster, besides, why we need to run heavy sub graph in parameter server? A simpler parameter server could bring incredible performance in distribution mode.

Tensorflow's PS running a subgraph from worker, variable/gradient need a send/recv from worker, which so many fragmented GRPC request. 
Compare to parameter server, we profiled Tensorflow's PS could process 10K request(RunGraphAsync) from workers, but a parameter server based on KV could deal with 100K or more request form workers.

Comment: I would guess there are fixable bugs/inefficiencies that make it slow. Google mainly focused on optimizing for large data transfers/long steps, so small loads didn't get enough attention. I would recommend making benchmark/profiling/filing bug. Recently a user made TensorFlow 10x faster for small tensor transfers by finding a root cause -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6116

Comment: BTW, overhead of pure `TF_Run` call is about 20 usec. If `RunGraphAsync` adds 180 usec of overhead, that seems too high

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, in our case, we hope to scale to thousands of workers, but using tensorflow's parameter server, only can scale to 200 workers(we already did some optimization, for native 1.21, 32 worker is the limitation). We profiled and found parameter server is so heavy.  but for now we need to decide whether we use tensorflow's ps or our own parameter server.

Comment: Using thousands of workers is a common use case in TensorFlow and should be optimized for fairly well. What is the bottleneck exactly? Are you sure the 200 usec is not due to the cost of synchronizing with so many workers?

Comment: 200us is the time of execution RunGraphAsync in parameter server side. in official version should be more that because recv op would wait for worker's sending tensor request.  When scale to 200 workers, parameter server(100 parameter server, with parameter partitions) become very heavy.